# How to Read text file and then display on table?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to extract data from a text file and put it into a DataTable. The content in the text file is in the following format:

```
ITEM NAME 1

Sold by: Amazon

$18.36



ITEM NAME 2

Sold by: Apple

$454.00
```

I want to display the data like this: 
[image: image description]

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: What code did you try if any...???? please check [ask] and also [mcve]